# Tracking gRPC internal limits in Java?

Tags: grpc-java

gRPC has various configurable limits, e.g. the number of concurrent streams in a channel:

https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/

Does gRPC output any telemetry data that allows you to catch in production if this or similar limits are being hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently in gRPC Java something out of the box that enforces a limit such as the one you describe.  Such a limit should be implemented as a custom Interceptor (ServerInterceptor or ClientInterceptor depending on where you want the control and tracking to happen) in which you can do anything you wish including such telemetry.